# Rename filenames in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to rename the filenames of edited photos so they are in sequence Windows Explorer.

The original filename is something like this: `IMG_1981.jpg` and after you have edited it, it saves as: `IMG_E1981.jpg`.

What I want to achieve is removing the `E` from the edited filename and adding some increment after the filename. Like `IMG_E1981.jpg` getting changed to `IMG_1981a.jpg` or `IMG_1981(1).jpg` and also to count incrementally if there is a matching filename. Eg `IMG_1981(2)`, `IMG_1981(3)` and so forth.

Any advice on a simple `.ps` script to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. So please show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about your current approch (please note the comment of Gerhard), you could try something like the following

For the below test-script I created a new directory that contains the script and a sub-directory `images`. This folder contains another directory called `renamed`. This allows us to have a look at the original files without renaming them

```
$img_path = "$PSScriptRoot\images"
$rename_path = "$PSScriptRoot\images\renamed"

foreach ($img in (Get-ChildItem "$img_path\*.jpg")) {
    # note the single quotes at the end - otherwise you need to escape the $-sign
    $new_name = $img.Name -replace "_E(\d\d\d\d)", '_$1'

    # no image with that name exists
    if (!(Test-Path "$rename_path\$new_name")) {
        Copy-Item $img "$rename_path\$new_name"
    } else {
        # image-name already used
        $i = 1
        $inc_name = $new_name -replace ".jpg", "_$i.jpg"
        # creating a new image-name by appending _1, _2, etc. until
        # the name is not already used
        while (Test-Path "$rename_path\$inc_name") {
            Write-Host "Found $inc_name"
            $i++
            $inc_name = $new_name -replace ".jpg", "_$i.jpg"
        }
        Copy-Item $img "$rename_path\$inc_name"
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is most certainly **not** the ideal way to solve this problem. Please try to explain your current problem a bit more detailed.

Since you say that you want to add something like `(0)` or `(1)` to the file name, if it already exists: **why** should names already exist? Feel free to share a demo-directory-content :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Razorfen. Your code is absolutely perfect. Your solution removed the "E" from the filename and verifies if there is a file with the same name and adds a _1 increment. Absolutely perfect! Thank you very much.

I use a Batch file to envoke the .PS1 script. Herewith the contents of the batch file:

```
PowerShell.exe -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
```

And herewith the contents of your code within the .ps1 file (with some minor modifications)

```
$img_path = ".\"
$rename_path = ".\"

foreach ($img in (Get-ChildItem "$img_path\IMG_E*.jpg")) {
    # note the single quotes at the end - otherwise you need to escape the $-sign
    $new_name = $img.Name -replace "_E(\d\d\d\d)", '_$1'

    # no image with that name exists
    if (!(Test-Path "$rename_path\$new_name")) {
        Copy-Item $img "$rename_path\$new_name"
    } else {
        # image-name already used
        $i = 1
        $inc_name = $new_name -replace ".jpg", "_$i.jpg"
        # creating a new image-name by appending _1, _2, etc. until
        # the name is not already used
        while (Test-Path "$rename_path\$inc_name") {
            Write-Host "Found $inc_name"
            $i++
            $inc_name = $new_name -replace ".jpg", "_$i.jpg"
        }
        Copy-Item $img "$rename_path\$inc_name"
    }
}
del IMG_E*.jpg
# deletes IMG_E*.jpg file as a new renamed copy was created above

del *.AAE
# deletes all *.AAE file from directory
```